# GDB not showing C code when gcc -g option is used

Tags: gcc, gdb

I have a file called `hello_world.c`.

I use the command `gcc -g -Wall hello_world.c`
Then `gdb ./a.out`
I set a breakpoint at line 27
And run, it tells me this:

> warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000

It doesn't show me the actual c code being executed line by line, it shows me

This when I break at l25

> Breakpoint 1, 0x000000000040052f in main ()

When I hit the breakpoint, and I use "l"

```
21  #include <stdlib.h>
22  #include <stdint.h>
23  
24  int main(int argc, char **argv) {
25    int a = 0xCAFEF00D, b = 0x13AECEE2;
26  
27    printf("The magic word is: %X\n", a + b);
28    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
29  }
```

Comment: Does you program even have 27 lines?  Try line 1 and see what happens.

Comment: type `l` as soon as you have the gdb prompt and add the result to the question. Works perfectly here.

Comment: It does have 27 lines, it has in main() in the question, and I think it's just not showing me the actual c code.

Comment: @Rmano Added the change you suggested.

Comment: Optimization? Try `gcc -g -O0 -Wall hello_world.c` (Otherwise, put your full file --- so people can try to reproduce).